# How can I set an Emacs buffer name using file local variables?

Tags: emacs

I have a directory structure where I have `<project>/worksheet.tex`.  When I open each worksheet, I get an undescriptive `worksheet<n>`as the name for the buffer.

I'd like to save the names of buffers as file local variables.
Something perhaps like:

```
;; (to be safe if "specific project" already exists as a buffer)
buffer-name: (generate-new-buffer-name "specific project")
```

How can this be implemented without using the `eval` file-local 'variable'?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can't, but if you answer `!` to the "potentially unsafe file-local variables" prompt, Emacs will note in your custom.el file that it should not prompt about that file's local variables in future.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't do what you want using file-local variables without the `eval:` pseudo-variable.

However, the `uniquify` library (which is standard), should cover your needs. Just put something like the following in your init file:

```
(require 'uniquify)
```

You can also customize the `uniquify-buffer-name-style` and `uniquify-separator` variables to tailor `uniquify` to your needs. I personally like these settings more than the defaults:

```
(setq
 uniquify-buffer-name-style 'post-forward
 uniquify-separator         ":")
```

Answer (score 2):

(update)
here's a solution with a file-local variable:

in your files:

```
;; -*- preferred-buffer-name: "purtsl"; -*-
```

in .emacs:

```
(defun change-buffer-name ()
  (if (boundp 'preferred-buffer-name)
      (rename-buffer preferred-buffer-name)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'change-buffer-name t)
```

you might have to customize *safe-local-variable-values* and/or *enable-local-variables*,
depending on how many projects you have, safety considerations and how annoying it is for you to answer the security question..

---

and here's a different approach. 
it checks for the name of the containing directory
and then changes the buffer's name to /WS:

```
(defun find-file-custom (filename)
  "open filename and set buffer name to <project>/WS"
  (interactive "F")
  (find-file filename)
  (rename-buffer (concat "<" (file-name-nondirectory
                       (directory-file-name
                        (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))) ">/WS")))
```